# Non-numerical input causes endless loop

Tags: c, loops, input, do-while

For some reason, if the user inputs the wrong data type, such as 'j' or '%', the loop will stop asking for input and will keep displaying `"Enter an integer >"` over and over. How can I make the program handle bad inputs? And why does entering a non-numerical value cause such strange behavior?

```
#define SENTINEL 0;
int main(void) {
  int sum = 0; /* The sum of numbers already read */
  int current; /* The number just read */

  do {
    printf("\nEnter an integer > ");
    scanf("%d", &current);
    if (current > SENTINEL)
      sum = sum + current;
  } while (current > SENTINEL);
  printf("\nThe sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: `scanf()` stops at the first non digit character. It keep that character in the buffer. The next time through the loop, the character is still there and `scanf` stops. The next time through the loop, the character is still there and `scanf` stops. The next time through the loop... ...

Comment: This code should not even compile because of the value of the `SENTINEL` macro. Probably you want to have `#define SENTINEL 0`.

Comment: That was just a typo. It was as you wrote it in the original program, and I fixed it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `scanf()` fails to find a matching input, the `current` variable will be unchanged: check return value of `scanf()`:

```
/* scanf() returns the number of assignments made.
   In this case, that should be 1. */
if (1 != scanf("%d", &current)) break;
```

If you wish to continue accepting inputs after an invalid input, the invalid data needs to be read from `stdin` as it will remain, as pointed out by [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) in the comments. One possible way would be to use the format specifier `"%*s"` that reads the input but performs no assignment:

```
if (1 != scanf("%d", &current))
{
    scanf("%*s");
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: So why doesn't the the program wait for user input in the next iteration of the loop? It just seems to skip over the scanf step.

Comment: @RobAlejandroVolgman, the input is unread, and is still there the next time `scanf()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to read the input into a string and then convert the string to the data type you want.

My C is a bit rusty, but I recall using `fgets()` to read the string, and then `sscanf()` to parse/"read" the string into the variables I was interested in.