# wrong input will exit the program c++

Tags: c++

So I have started to learn c++ and I have wrote this simple program , when a user inputs wrong number it gives an option to try again however when a user inputs any characters it gives the option to try again and directly exits the program why is that happening ?
`

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){


int a;
char b ,c;

start:


    printf("INPUT ONLY NUMBER 1 : ");

    scanf(" %d", &a);

    if(a==1)
    {
        printf( " you entered correctly \n");
        printf("do you want to try again? <Y> <N> \n");
        scanf(" %c", &c);

        if(c=='Y' ||c=='y')

        {
            goto start;
        }

    }
else {
    sleep (1);
    printf("wrong number , do you want to try again? <Y> <N> \n");
    scanf(" %c" , &b);



}

if (b=='Y'||b=='y')
{
sleep(1);
goto start;
}

else
if(b=='n'||b=='N') 
{

sleep(1);
printf("thank you and goodbye");
exit (1);
}
}
```

`

Comment: If user inputs a wrong number it works fine , it only exit when a user inputs a character

Comment: "so i have started to learn c++" - well this looks like C, not C++. Sure you picked the right book? Anyway,: get a better book! `goto` has its application, but a beginner should **not** start with it! The 1970ies/80ies are long gone, use structured code! And format&indent the code properly.

Comment: use while loop instead of goto statement

Comment: but i want to know why is that happening?

Comment: Re-write the code with a a loop-statement and use C++ iostreams, not C-style. Then try again. If that is too complicated, start with something easier. Alsos see [ask].

Comment: @noname I'm not one of those who will tell you that goto is evil but don't use it if it's not absolutely necessary. Especially if you're beginner, try to rewrite your code with a simple while loop and you'll probably find your mistake and correct it automatically

Comment: thomas can you give an example of how the code would look like if i had to use while , i am not yet familiar to while , i thought goto statement was easy

Comment: thank you olaf but i needed to know what exactly is causing the program to exit when entered a character in "INPUT ONLY NUMBER 1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-numerical input causes endless loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314246/non-numerical-input-causes-endless-loop), but with opposite result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf(" %d")`
I bet your problem comes from that space before the `%d`. Try `scanf("%d")`. Same later: `scanf("%c")` instead of `scanf(" %c ")`.

Anyway, your code is VERY dirty. And this looks like C, not C++.
Not trying to be a maniac here, but you should indent properly and AVOID the `goto` BY ALL MEANS. Your program structure is simple and a `while` loop will do the trick for you. You should also avoid to explicitly call `exit(1)`. `exit` is mostly used to provoke premature termination. In your case, your program reaches its end normally, and you should exit with your `main` function's `return 0`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>        //Reauired to use boolean type in C

int main()
{
    bool stop = false;      //boolean type only has two states: true and false. Very useful for loops!
    while(!stop)            //Read as "While we don't need to stop, execute the loop's contents
    {                       //Much easier to read!
        printf("INPUT ONLY NUMBER 1 : ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if(a == 1)
        {
            printf("you entered correctly \n");
            printf("do you want to try again? <Y> <N>\n");
            scanf("%c", &c);

            if(c == 'N' || c == 'n')
            {                   //We only need to tell the loop when to stop
                stop = true;    //by setting stop to true 
            }                   //The loop's default behavior is to loop execution of its content
        }
        else
        {
            sleep(1);

            printf("wrong number , do you want to try again? <Y> <N> \n");
            scanf("%c" , &b);

            if(b=='n'|| b=='N') 
            {
                stop = true;    //Same as above
            }

            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    printf("thank you and goodbye");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something left behind from your scanf, which sometimes you can clean that up flushing it, but in your code seems not to work.

Having a look at that issue this comes across:
http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Which basically tells you that if your approach does not work, then you should change it. 
Hope this help, you also asked about while in one of your questions there, so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    char input;
    char try_again;

    do {
        std::cout << "INPUT ONLY NUMBER:";
        std::cin >> input;
        // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit
        // does not return a bool, you can check that >0
        if (std::isdigit(input)) {
             // do what you want.
             std::cout << "digit\n";
             continue;
        }  else {
            // you can as for more imput like:
            std::cout << "Not a number, try again?(y/Y):";
            std::cin >> try_again;
            std::tolower(try_again);
            if (try_again == 'y') {
                continue; // will start the loop again.
            } else {
                break; // it will exit the loop.
        }
        }
    } while(true);

    return 0;

    }
```